# Update Error in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, cuda

```
sudo apt-get update
```

leads me to:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease:  
    The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public 
    key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FCAE110B1118213C
```

How can I get the key?

Comment: try : `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FCAE110B1118213C`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with an other key. Like Serverus Tux already said, try to add the missing key. It solved my problem.

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FCAE110B1118213C`

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the problem by deleting the GPG key **`1118213C`** of the **Graphics Drivers Team**.

Adding `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` again should solve the issue.

Execute : `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

Why does it work? While adding the Launchpad PPA back, you see :

```
gpg: requesting key 1118213C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
```